# Insert multiple rows with one select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert multiple rows into a table, with a single select to get an ID from another table.

For instance, if I have the following:

```sql
create table book (
id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
title varchar not null
);

create table chapter (
id uuid primary key gen_random_uuid(),
title varchar not null,
book_id uuid references book(id) not null
);

insert into book ("title")
select "foo bar";
```

I want to insert some chapters for a single book, each as their own row, whose title I know but not the ID, how can I do this in a single query?

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```sql
insert into chapter ("title", "book_id")
select
  values ("Chapter One", "Second Chapter")
  book.id
from book
where book.title = "foo bar";
```

The resulting chapter table is something like:

```
chapter
-----
id, title, book_id
8e7fb95b-7bde-45fb-bd81-fba4e29652c0, "Chapter One", eef8e56c-95d4-452b-bd64-ceccae435495
afdd22d3-bfc0-4382-b275-20f89ca0bc03, "Second Chapter", eef8e56c-95d4-452b-bd64-ceccae435495
```

Comment: each chapter should be it's own row

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to do it, but if you want to use the clause `VALUES` to collect the `chapters` you can try using a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html):

```
WITH j (chapter_title) AS (
  VALUES ('fist chapter'),('second chapter')
) 
INSERT INTO chapter (book_id , title) 
SELECT book.id, j.chapter_title FROM j,book
WHERE book.title = 'foo bar';
```